# Send confirmation email to two users

Tags: function, parameters, php

I'm trying to send a confirmation email to two members but im confused as how to do so. Below is only the relevant code.
Ive used PHP mail before in my website for a contact page, which is fine, but I don't know how to send it to more than one person. Can you tell me what im doing wrong please?

Function exchange:

```
 //full code for exchange not included

// Redirect to index page if exchange is successful  
if ($success){
        sendMail($coinsAvail['Email'],$valueResultAdd['Email'],$valueResultAdd['OddJobName']);
        header("location: index.php?success=yes&email={$valueResultAdd['Email']}");
    }
        else{
            if($success)
             header("location: index.php?success=no&email={$valueResultAdd['Email']}");
        }
        exit();

function to send email
    }
    //Send a confirmation email to both members
    function sendMail($purchaseEmail, $oddjobEmail, $oddJobName)
    {
        $to = "$purchaseEmail, $oddjobEmail";
        $subject = "$oddJobName";
        $message = "Hello! $oddJobName has been requested by $purchaseEmail.";
        $from = "someonelse@example.com";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        echo "Mail Sent.";  
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To send it to many people, just use the 'comma' seperator like how you send emails to multiple people via your yahoo, gmail accounts.

Answer (score 3):

According the the [Mail PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

> The formatting of this string must comply with » RFC 2822. Some
>   examples are:
>
> user@example.com user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com User
>    User , Another User

So in your case you can do like that:

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

mail($to, 'the subject', 'the message', null,
   '-fwebmaster@example.com');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work, assuming $coinsAvail['Email'] and $valueResultAdd['Email'] are both email addresses.  I would use an echo($to); in the function to make sure the $to string looks the way you're wanting.